# Why is Automapper using so much memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, automapper, .net-4.5

I am using the latest version of Automapper (v3.0.0.0-ci1036) and when it converts an object with binary data, it uses crazy amounts of memory. (200MB for a 10MB file). Here is an example of such a "file" beging converted:

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        convertObject();
    }

    private static void convertObject()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var fileContents = new Byte[1024 * 1024 * 10];
        rnd.NextBytes(fileContents);

        var attachment = new Attachment { Content = fileContents };

        Mapper.CreateMap<Attachment, AttachmentDTO>();
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to convert");
        Console.ReadLine();
        var dto = Mapper.Map<Attachment, AttachmentDTO>(attachment);
        Console.WriteLine(dto.Content.Length + " bytes");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentDTO
{
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or do I have to stop using automapper for objects that contain binary data?

Comment: Does it spike then go back to normal after it maps?

Comment: Nope, it stays that way until the application is killed

Comment: One reason might be you use array of bytes: an array of bytes requires all bytes in memory to be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but your reason might be the following:

Your C# application works on the .NET runtime which clear the heap memory when possible using the Garbage Collector.

This technique has the side effect to fragment your heap memory. So, for example, you might have 100MB allocated, with the 40% available for new variables that is fragmented in smaller chunks of max 5MB.

In this situation, when you allocate a new array of 10 MB, the .NET virtual machine has not room to allocate it, even if it has 40MB free.

To solve the problem it move up your available heap memory to 110MB (in the best case) and allocate the new 10 MB for your new byte array.

Also see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882521.aspx#id0400035